# role based access in spring security using JWT

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I recently integrated `JWT` with `Spring-Security` in a `Spring-boot` app. The Authentication part is working fine. But, role based Authorisation is not working as expected.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

public WebSecurityConfig( UserDetailsService userDetailsService )
{
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
}

@Override
protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
{
    http.csrf().disable()

            .authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()

            .antMatchers("/rest/user/hello").hasRole("ADMIN")

            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()

            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))

            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));

    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
}

public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

public JWTAuthenticationFilter( AuthenticationManager auth )
{
    authenticationManager = auth;
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res )
        throws AuthenticationException
{
    try
    {
        UserModel creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), UserModel.class);

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUserName(),
                creds.getPassword(), Collections.<GrantedAuthority> emptyList()));
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
        Authentication auth ) throws IOException, ServletException
{

    String role = auth.getAuthorities().iterator().next().toString();

    String token = Jwts.builder().claim("role",role).setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000000l))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, Constant.SECRET).compact();
    res.addHeader(Constant.HEADER_STRING, Constant.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    String tokenJsonResponse = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString("Ok");
    res.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.getWriter().print(tokenJsonResponse);
}
}

public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

public JWTAuthorizationFilter( AuthenticationManager authManager )
{
    super(authManager);
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain )
        throws IOException, ServletException
{
    String header = req.getHeader(Constant.HEADER_STRING);

    if( header == null || !header.startsWith(Constant.TOKEN_PREFIX) )
    {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        return;
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication( HttpServletRequest request )
{
    String token = request.getHeader(Constant.HEADER_STRING);
    if( token != null )
    {
        // parse the token.
        String user = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(Constant.SECRET)
                .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(Constant.TOKEN_PREFIX, "")).getBody().getSubject();

        if( user != null )
        {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, Collections.<GrantedAuthority> emptyList());
        }
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

If I debug while logging into the application, it shows `Authentication` has `role=ADMIN` in  authorities [image]

But after logging in if I send request to `/rest/user/hello`, it is throwing exception with message `Access Denied`, even though the logged in user has ADMIN role. How to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to use it as   ``` antMatchers("/admin").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")  ```  see here . https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authorize-requests

Comment: In the above link, it still has `.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")  ` without `access`?

Comment: point no 3 says. Any URL that starts with "/admin/" will be restricted to users who have the role "ROLE_ADMIN".